# Regex for line block starting with specific character?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Question:

Given the following text file:

```
blablabla
# Block 1
# Some text
## Some more text
### Even more text
### Hello
# Some text
### Again Text
# Blank lines or lines not starting with # terminate

blablabala
# Block 1
# Some text
## Some more text
### Even more text
### Hello
# Some text
### Again Text
# Blank lines or lines not starting with # terminate
blablabla
```

Is it possible to extract all BLOCKS of lines that start with # with a regular expression ?
**Note:** 
The block should be ONE string, just extracting all lines starting with # is trivial.

**Additional question:**
Is it possible to get the number of leading # in a regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(#.*([\n]|$))+");
var matches = regex.Matches(sample_string);
```

with `sample_string` set to your example returns two matches, `matches[0]` for the first block and `matches[1]` for the 2nd.

Comment: @ShafqatMasood: it works for me when testing it with Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually neither mine nor your solution work for all test cases, working on it.

Comment: Please unaccept this answer. It works for the test case you gave but not for some modified ones I used.

Comment: @Dirk: Almost, you need to account for the fact that the last line doesn't necessarely have to end with \n, so it must be: "(#.*(\n|$))+"

Answer (score 0):

```
  Regex RE = new Regex(@"\n+#.*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
  MatchCollection theMatches = RE.Matches(text);
  theMatches.Count; //gives number of matches
```

I used [regex.com](http://www.regexe.com/) to test if my regex was working fine.

```
 string str = @"blablabla
                # Block 1
                # Some text
                ## Some more text
                ### Even more text
                ### Hello
                # Some text
                ### Again Text
                # Blank lines or lines not starting with # terminate";
        Regex RE = new Regex(@"\n+#.*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        MatchCollection theMatches = RE.Matches(str);
        theMatches.Count.ToString();
         foreach (Match match in theMatches)
         {
                 Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
         }
```

out put is

'# Block 1

'# Some text

'## Some more text

'### Even more text

'### Hello

'# Some text

'### Again Text

'# Blank lines or lines not starting with # terminate

Comment: i have use the visual studio and with the same input as u mentioned it is working fine